# Error installing python module lxml on osx mavericks

Tags: python, macos, lxml, osx-mavericks

Here is my python env: note that numpy is working

```
13:41:44/shared:5 $python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from numpy import *
>>> print mat([1,2,3])
[[1, 2, 3]]
>>>
```

But I am unable to install lxml.  What is missing in my python and/or os configuration to make this work:

```
13:37:03/shared:4 $pip install --upgrade lxml
Downloading/unpacking lxml
  Downloading lxml-3.2.4.tar.gz (3.3MB): 3.3MB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package lxml
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Building lxml version 3.2.4.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28

    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.py'
    warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'src/lxml/tests'
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Building lxml version 3.2.4.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/private/var/folders/k4/l5ww32y14svd5wmkgzzftl9m0000gn/T/pip_build_steve/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -flat_namespace
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-flat_namespace'
    In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:314:
    **/private/var/folders/k4/l5ww32y14svd5wmkgzzftl9m0000gn/T/pip_build_steve/lxml/src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:9:10: fatal error: 'libxml/xmlversion.h' file not found
    #include "libxml/xmlversion.h"**
             ^
    1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you are missing libxml/xmlversion.h

Since it seems that **/usr/include/libxml2** is being included, I think the most probable reason is that you don't have libxml2 installed on your system. This is most likely due to missing "command line tools". Get them here: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?=command%20line%20tools

Can also be solved by installing libxml2 via macports or brew (**But don't do this other than as last resort**). Using system libraries instead of homebrew or macports whenever possible can save you from a lot of incompatibility pitfalls.

Comment: Hi i reinstalled libxml2 via homebrew. maybe the upgrade to mavericks 10.9.1 overwrote the prior install. Will get back here.

Comment: I did "brew install libxml2" which was successful. But "pip install --upgrade lxml" still fails with same error

Comment: Have you checked that /usr/include/libxml2 exists? I bet it doesn't, in which case my recommendation is to install command line tools from Apple. Preferring system libs when both system and homebrew are available will almost always save you some headache. PS. The reason why homebrew-libxml didn't solve it is that that `/usr/local/include` probably isn't included by pip while building. Before trying to hack that, I'd really suggest checking /usr/include and installing command line tools - that will probably solve it all :)

Comment: You are correct - the /usr/include/libxml2 does not exist.  I just upgraded to 10.9.1 - did that wipe out the command line tools??

Comment: Yep. The "command line tools" are OS-specific and need to be re-installed each time you upgrade to a new "major version" of OSX.

Comment: I just went from 10.9 to 10.9.1  sounds like a 'minor' upgrade .. ? In any case I did just reinstall the xcode tools. Will try again the above steps.

Comment: Sounds good. 10.9 -> 10.9.1 cannot have caused this, but 10.8.5 -> 10.9.x definitely could. Anyways: I hope this solves it :)

Comment: actually 10.9 -> 10.9.1 DID cause this.  After re installing xcode tools the lxml install is going forward.  "Successfully installed lxml"

Comment: This is working now,  i have upvoted  pls consider likewise for my question.

Comment: This worked for me: STATIC_DEPS=true easy_install 'lxml>=3.3.4'